# topology: embedding

Tags: general-topology

Billingsley writes in his book convergence of probability measures:
" If $S$ can be embedded as an open set in a some complete metric space, then it is topologically complete".

I have taken one course in analysis (I am not from maths background
) which covers chapters 1-6 and some parts of chapter 7, and I can make nothing out of this statement. I guess he is looking for some sort of map?

Comment: Does he give a definition of "topologically complete"? The usual completeness is not a topological property.

Comment: Are you sure it is open set?

Comment: [rel link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380870/dieudonne-complete-and-topologically-complete-are-equivalent-for-every-space-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First just to handle some definitions:

- By an *embedding* of a topological space $X$ into a topological space $Y$ we mean a (one-to-one) function $f : X \to Y$ such that if you consider it as a mapping into $f [X]$, the range of $f$, then it is a homeomorphism onto this subspace of $Y$.
- A topological space $X$ is called *topologically complete* if there is a complete metric $d$ on $X$ which yields the same open sets (*i.e.*, the topology can be induced by a complete metric on that same space).

So the meaning of this statement is essentially this

> If $S$ is a topological space which is homeomorphic to an open subspace of a complete metric space $Y$, then the topology on $S$ is induced by a complete metric (you can give $S$ a complete metric which yields the same open sets).

Actually, a stronger statement is also true:

> If $S$ is a topological space which is homeomorphic to a G$_\delta$ subspace (a countable intersection of open sets) of a complete metric space $Y$, then the topology on $S$ is induced by a complete metric.

---

To give a bit of an example: Consider the open interval $S = (0,1)$ with the usual subspace topology.  As $S$ is itself an open subspace of the real line $\mathbb{R}$, it follows by the statement that $S$ is *topologically complete*.  But we know that the usual metric on $S$ is not complete: the Cauchy sequence $\langle \frac1n \rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge to any point in $S$.  However we can give $S$ a *different* metric -- namely $$d^\prime (x,y) = \left| \tan \left( \frac{2\pi x - \pi}2 \right) - \tan \left( \frac{2\pi y - \pi}2 \right) \right|$$
and show that this metric is both complete, and yields the same open sets.  It is not too hard to see that the sequence mentioned above is *not* Cauchy with respect to the $d^\prime$ metric.

Comment: what is the name of this result? i wanted to see the proof

Comment: @user17523: I'm not sure if it is a named theorem, but it can be found in Kechris, _Classical Descriptive Set Theory_ (Theorem 3.11, p.17).  It is closely related to _Lavrentiev's Theorem_ which states that if $A,B$ are subspaces of complete metric spaces $X,Y$, respectively, and $f : A \to B$ is a homeomorphism between these subspaces, then there are G$_\delta$ subsets $A \subseteq G \subseteq X$,$B \subseteq H \subseteq Y$ such that $f$ may be extended to a homeomorphism between $G$ and $H$.